# CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22

Tags: debian, network-shares, samba, cifs

I currently face an issue that I wasn't able to connect to a Windows Share. Following my used command, fstab doesn't helped either, it will get the same error. The kernel log isn't useful @ all.

The only thing i have changed from my call to posed it here is the USER/DOMAIN

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs //NT-SERVER03/NEW-DFS/EA/SE/Shared/ /media/austausch -o vers=2.0,rw,nounix,sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials domain=XXXX
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=172.24.0.3,unc=\\NT-SERVER03\NEW-DFS,vers=2.0,nounix,sec=ntlmv2,user=XXXX,domain=XXXX,prefixpath=EA/SE/Shared,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Kernel Log:

```
Jan 26 12:47:58 brabender kernel: [10015.152915] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

I hope someone knows what I a missing.

Thanks for your Help. Lars